# ToC not clickable

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, compiling

I've started to use LaTeX recently and I'm having some problems with the ToC.
I need a `ToC` with clickable links to the chapter of my thesis, that's the code I wrote:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage{hyperref}


\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\addto\captionsitalian{
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {Indice}%
}

\title{
    {La Domotica}\\
}

\author{My Name}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Introduzione}
\end{document}
```

As you can see I've included `hyperref` but the ToC is still not clickable.

EDIT:
Just found the solution. I'm using sharelatex and I selected fast compile mode, that's why the ToC wasn't clickable.

Comment: For me your code produces a clickable toc. Which pdf viewer are you using? How did you compile?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX-SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please have a look at our [starter page](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro. The MWE is also clickable for me.

Comment: If the compilation is done with `latex+dvips` only there won't be hyperlinks, of course

Comment: Just found the solution. I'm using sharelatex and I selected fast compile mode, that's why the ToC wasn't clickable. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP discover that she/he use wrong compilation mode in sharelatex.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because   it was solved choosing the appropriate compilation type in ShareLaTeX.

Comment: @Zarko simultaneous idea!

Comment: @CarLaTeX, it seems that we are well tuned team :-)